# ModelState.isvalid is false when trying to save an entity, error says a field is required in a related entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code to save an entity

```
 public class TipoDeProducto
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int TipoDeProductoId{ get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El nombre debe tener como máximo 50 caractéres")]
        public string Nombre { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool Estado { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Producto> Productos { get; set; }
    }
```

and Product

```
 public class Producto
    {
        [Key]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int ProductoId { get; set; }

        public int TipoDeProductoId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "El nombre debe tener como máximo 50 caractéres")]
        public string NombreProducto { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "La descripción debe tener como máximo 300 caractéres")]
        public string Descripcion { get; set; }

        public bool Estado { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey("TipoDeProductoId")]
        public virtual TipoDeProducto TipoDeProducto { get; set; }
    }
```

The edit (POST) is this:

```
  public HttpResponseMessage PutTipoDeProducto(int id, TipoDeProducto tipoDeProducto)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
            }

            if (id != tipoDeProducto.TipoDeProductoId)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }

            try
            {
                unitOfWork.TipoDeProductoRepository.Update(tipoDeProducto);
                unitOfWork.Save();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

My index view is like this:

```
@model List<PowerData.Comisiones.Models.TipoDeProducto>
    @using PowerData.Comisiones.Models
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Tipos de producto";
    }

    <h2>Tipos de producto</h2>

    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TipoDeProducto>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.Nombre).Title("Nombre");
        columns.Bound(p => p.Estado).Title("Estado");
        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); });
    })
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))

    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(430))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .WebApi()
        //.Ajax()
        //.ServerOperation(false)
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.TipoDeProductoId);
            model.Field(p => p.TipoDeProductoId).Editable(false);
        })

        .Create(create => create.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeProductos" }))) // Action invoked when the user saves a new data item
                    .Read(read => read.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeProductos" }))) // Action invoked when the grid needs data
                    .Update(update => update.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeProductos", id = "{0}" })))  // Action invoked when the user saves an updated data item
                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Url(Url.HttpRouteUrl("DefaultApi", new { controller = "TipoDeProductos", id = "{0}" }))) // Action invoked when the user removes a data item

        //.Create(update => update.Action("Create", "TipoDeCanales"))
            //.Read(read => read.Action("Read", "TipoDeCanales"))
            //.Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "TipoDeCanales"))
            //.Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "TipoDeCanales"))
    )
    )
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function error_handler(e) {
            if (e.errors) {
                var message = "Errors:\n";
                $.each(e.errors, function (key, value) {
                    if ('errors' in value) {
                        $.each(value.errors, function () {
                            message += this + "\n";
                        });
                    }
                });
                toastr.error(message)
                //alert(message);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

However, after I add items, and then try to edit an existing row, the Model.Isvalid = false, and when I check the validation errors, it says ProductName is required, which is not even a field on the table I am trying to save, its a related list of entitties

Comment: Could you please add the generated HTML of your page as it looks just before you submit? There may be an issue with the binding due to invalid or mismatching IDs in your HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably default model binder is trying to bind the related entity `productos` as well. You can override that using the `Bind` attribute (`[Bind(Exclude="")]`) like

```
  public HttpResponseMessage PutTipoDeProducto(int id, [Bind(Exclude="productos")]TipoDeProducto tipoDeProducto)
   {
         //code here
   }
```

Comment: not working, I checked end the navigation property is still bound, with all properties set to 0, null or empty and model.isvalid is still false

Comment: even after setting the `Bind` attribute? that's strange and not possible. Check if in any other action method you are using the same model and there also exclude the related entity.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I do to ensure the validation applies to the current entity only:

```
        foreach (var key in ModelState.Keys)
            if (key.Split('.').Length > 2)
                ModelState[key].Errors.Clear();

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

The check for the number of occurrences of `.` means: if the modelstate key is something like `currentDTO.relatedDTO.field` then that validation error is ignored (cleared). If it's just something like `id` or `currentDTO.validateThisField`, then it doesn't get cleared.